# Why does one take $\inf ||x-a||$ for $d(x,A)$?

Tags: measure-theory, definition, supremum-and-infimum

Why does one take $\inf ||x-a||$ for $d(x,A)$?

Why not just take exactly $||x-a||$? Or $\sup ||x-a||$ (this would not offer measurability though, because it could "explode" to a very big number)?

Comment: Over which index set is the infimum taken? I cannot understand the question as written.

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez Over $a \in A$.

Comment: Then you mean $d(x,A)$ instead of $d(x,a)$? If $a \in A$ is part of the infimum it is pretty much a "local" variable that doesn't mean anything outside that formula.

Answer (score 5):

I think that you are mixing two concepts here. If $x$ is a point in a normed vector space:

- the distance from $x$ to a point $a$ is $\|x-a\|$;
- the distance from $x$ to a set $A$ is $\inf\{\|x-a\|\,|\,a\in A\}$.

Comment: Is it assumed that in the second case $x \not \in A$? Because if $x$ was in $A$ then one could take exact distance?

Comment: @mavavilj No, we don't assume that $x\notin A$. But if $x\in A$, then $d(x,A)=0(=d(x,x))$.